# Magento 2.3 setup:upgrade error sql

Tags: database, magento2.3, setup-upgrade

I used magento 2.3 and meet problem when run command upgrade.
It shows:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

I try some solution about mysql variable as:

> max_allowed_packet=4000M
>    and wait_timeout=6000

However, nothing solve it.
Just see the of sql:

```
key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=5
max_threads=151
thread_count=6
connection_count=5
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 67870 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fb47d30cc00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 700002904e90 thread_stack 0x46000
0   mysqld                              0x000000010f38a5ec my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char*, unsigned long) + 60
1   mysqld                              0x000000010e7e7e76 handle_fatal_signal + 678
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff66a1cf5a _sigtramp + 26
3   ???                                 0x00007000029011e8 0x0 + 123145345307112
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff667ba1ae abort + 127
5   mysqld                              0x000000010f71707c ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long) + 252
6   mysqld                              0x000000010f6b3542 row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 4002
7   mysqld                              0x000000010f58ffd1 ha_innobase::index_read(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, ha_rkey_function) + 657
8   mysqld                              0x000000010e3e8389 handler::ha_index_read_map(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, ha_rkey_function) + 233
9   mysqld                              0x000000010e65ec30 join_read_key(QEP_TAB*) + 464
10  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aa28 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 728
11  mysqld                              0x000000010e65b0fa evaluate_join_record(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*) + 602
12  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aae1 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 913
13  mysqld                              0x000000010e65b0fa evaluate_join_record(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*) + 602
14  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aae1 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 913
15  mysqld                              0x000000010e65b0fa evaluate_join_record(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*) + 602
16  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aae1 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 913
17  mysqld                              0x000000010e65b0fa evaluate_join_record(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*) + 602
18  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aae1 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 913
19  mysqld                              0x000000010e65b0fa evaluate_join_record(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*) + 602
20  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aae1 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 913
21  mysqld                              0x000000010e65b0fa evaluate_join_record(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*) + 602
22  mysqld                              0x000000010e65aae1 sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) + 913
23  mysqld                              0x000000010e6557da JOIN::exec() + 858
24  mysqld                              0x000000010e6ee8c1 handle_query(THD*, LEX*, Query_result*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 545
25  mysqld                              0x000000010e6b1420 execute_show(THD*, TABLE_LIST*) + 624
26  mysqld                              0x000000010e61e55a Sql_cmd_show::execute(THD*) + 74
27  mysqld                              0x000000010e6abc51 mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool) + 3473
28  mysqld                              0x000000010e6a9af6 mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*) + 886
29  mysqld                              0x000000010e6a8408 dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command) + 7544
30  mysqld                              0x000000010e6a9363 do_command(THD*) + 467
31  mysqld                              0x000000010e7d10e4 handle_connection(void*) + 372
32  mysqld                              0x000000010f77ebbc pfs_spawn_thread(void*) + 316
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff66a26661 _pthread_body + 340
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff66a2650d _pthread_body + 0
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff66a25bf9 thread_start + 13

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fb47d31a828): SHOW INDEXES FROM catalog_category_product_index_tmp WHERE `Non_unique` = 1
Connection ID (thread ID): 58
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I am using Mac Os with mysql. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you double your thread_cache_size, stop/start try again?  If it worked, please let us know and Upvote/Accept the answer of March 1, 2019, please.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
1) last 600 lines of your MySQL error.log after this failure.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after min 2 hours UPTIME, before the UPGRADE attempt.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: The max_allowed_packet GLOBAL VARIABLE has an upper limit of 1G.   4000M would not be possible.  Do you still need assistance with this MySQL instance configuration to prevent run time problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT @@thread_cache_size;  for information on your current TCS.

Double the count in your my.cnf [mysqld] section, stop/start and try your process.

Good luck, view my profile, Network profile please.

Comment: I have added but it still have problem

Comment: @thelight Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. RAM size of your MySQL Host server 1) last 600 lines of your MySQL error.log after this failure. A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after min 2 hours UPTIME, before the UPGRADE attempt. C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @the light  Would like to help you, if requested information could be posted.